# modifying wireless network driver by adding data structure to it

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I barely have any knowledge about writing a device driver. But now I am starting to work on a project which requires modification to the wireless network driver.

I am actually using the Intel Wifi Link 5300 card. So I'm basically trying to modify the iwl-5000.c. In this project, the driver has to access several tables to set transmission parameters in real time. The number of elements of the tables will not exceed 100. But I have no idea as to where to put the tables. Putting them in the kernel with the source code takes up memory. Putting them in user space takes time to access them, also not easy to implement it. Could anyone suggest a good feasible way to implement this?

Comment: I would send an email to ilw@linux.intel.com and ask there what the best way would be

Comment: You can find and modify the iwl-5000.c file here, for example: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/ Then compile and install the driver. I don't have any idea what or where to write in order to accomplish your objective.